# Missing required field "grant_type" in dropbox API

Tags: php, dropbox-api, guzzle

I'm trying to use dropbox api to show main list folder, and I have a lot of problems when I try to have an access token from an authorized user.

My code is very simple, I get the code from giving permissions to my app. And the request to retrieve the token is this.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

try{
//    $response = $client->get("https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=". $client_id . "&response_type=code");

    $response = $client->post("https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token",
        array(
            'json'  => array(
                'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
                'code' => '********ZJtDI'
            ),
            'auth'      => array(
                $client_id,
                $client_secret
            ), 
        ));

    echo $response->getBody();

}catch ( \Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

Client error: `POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error_description": "missing required field \"grant_type\"", "error": "invalid_request"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your POST request must contain `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded POST data, not a JSON string. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-token. And read http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#post-form-requests for sending a POST request with normal form fields.

Answer (score 1):

As Progman said, you have to use usual form type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) instead of JSON.

With Guzzle it's simple:

```
$response = $client->post("https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token",
    array(
        'form_params' => array(
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => '********ZJtDI',
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        ),
    )
);
```